# Javascript Value Assignment Delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm at a loss right now. I'm using a simple variable, whose value is assigned during a loop. After exiting the loop, the value of the variable is still undefined, **unless** I alert it's value first. Then everything works fine. What's going on here?

```
$(myarray).each(function(idx, item)
{
     fetchSomethingRemotely( success: function(data) {
           item.someValue = data; });

     // if the following alert is not there, doSomething will never get called
     // and the alert after the else will show item.someValue as undefined.
     alert(item.someValue);

     if (item.someValue != null) { doSomething(item.someValue); }
     else { alert(item.someValue); }

});
```

**Edit:**

Okay, so I've got a better handle in this now. The value assignment (item.someValue=123) happens inside of a callback function within this iteration. So the value is probably not there yet when I serially try to access it a couple of code lines below. How could I wait for the value to be assigned?

Comment: can u post the code you wrote?

Comment: I think everyone is in agreement that you should post some code. :)

Comment: The message seems to be pretty clear, that it needs some code :)

Comment: I'm making a quick test case that crystallizes the issue. I'll edit shortly.

Comment: Looks like we need some more code now. :) What we have now still doesn't define your problem fully. In fact, your code works fine without the `alert`, assuming a dummy `myarray` of string objects.

Comment: +1 @casablanca - Definitely needs more code at this point. My guess is it has something to do with DOM loading and alert causes a delay.

Comment: "How could I wait for the value to be assigned?" - why can't you put the code in that callback function? That is the point of callback functions passed to asynchronous tasks, and you've implied that fetchSomethingRemotely(...) is asynchronous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How could I wait for the value to be assigned?

The answer is already in your code. Just move `doSomething` into the callback function.

```
fetchSomethingRemotely( { success: function(data) {
       item.someValue = data;
       if (item.someValue != null) doSomething(item.someValue);
} });
```

Note that this will still move on to the next item before the current item has got its value. If you must perform all of the iteration sequentially, you can do something like this:

```
function iterate(index) {
  var item = myarray[index];
  fetchSomethingRemotely( { success: function(data) {
    item.someValue = data;
    if (item.someValue != null) doSomething(item.someValue);
    if (index < myarray.length - 1) iterate(index + 1);
  } });
}
```

And then you would fire off the whole process with `iterate(0)`.

Comment: I solved it slightly differently as I didn't want the processing in the callback by adding counters (started operations and completed operations) and then comparing those values in a loop until they match, and then proceed. But this is a good solution too.

Comment: @Alex: Do you mean you're running an idle loop until the counters match? That can potentially lead to a deadlock (read: freeze your browser) if the browser runs all JavaScript in a single thread, not to mention you're wasting CPU cycles.

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to use `var` to define the variable. Are you sure the variable exists in the scopes you are using it. If you do `for ( var i ...` then it will only exist in the `for` scope, not outside it. You can use Webkit (Chrome, Safari)'s Developer Tools to debug your script by setting a breakpoint on the problem line, and then in the right column you can see all variables defined in the related scopes.

Comment: JavaScript does not have block level scope. A `var`  inside a `for` will have function level scope or global scope.

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing to set the breakpoint to. Either it works (with the alert there) or it doesn't.

Comment: Anurag good point. Guess I wrote that as spending a few hours debugging something like that before in my life. I wonder if all browsers treat this the same.

Comment: Alex, breakpoint the line before alert. If the variable is in the scope you are good. At least it's a start to figuring it out.

Comment: How could it be out of scope. I'm iterating through an array of objects and set the value of its property explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

> "How could I wait for the value to be
>   assigned?"

Welcome to asyncronous programming!

You're going to need to put *everything* in the callback, not just the variable assignment.